# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_site__old

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a webpage using python and mezzanine as its cms.
but I got this error after successfully creating Superuser:

```
    Superuser created successfully.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_site__old

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\annie\Documents\DMCproject\manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\core\management\commands\createdb.py", line 61, in handle
    func()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\core\management\commands\createdb.py", line 109, in create_pages
    call_command("loaddata", "mezzanine_required.json")
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 131, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 69, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 115, in loaddata
    connection.check_constraints(table_names=table_names)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 276, in check_constraints
    cursor.execute(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixtures: no such table: django_site__old
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to this issue in Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29182.
It is caused by a new behavior introduced in sqlite 3.26.
Django has patched it in latest 2.0 and 2.1, but mezzanine does not support Django 2 yet.

The easiest fix is to not use sqlite - switch to postgres, mysql, etc. Alternatively, downgrade sqlite to < 3.26

https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1910

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a github action and I had to tweak the ubuntu version to get the preinstalled sqlite version that would work. What fixed the issue for me was to change this line:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

to

```
runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
```

Got the ubuntu version containing the sqlite version I needed here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sqlite3.